# "has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes" when accessing the spring boot API

Tags: angular, spring, web

I am trying to run the application, the front end is developed using angular 15, and the backend uses spring boot 3.0.1.  when I try to access I get the following error on the chrome
browser:

[image: error on chrome]
I have applied @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") on the controller level but didn't work out I also tried using the code below but am getting the same issue. I would appreciate your help.

```
@Configuration
```

public class AppConf implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .allowedMethods("GET").allowedHeaders("*");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is something you need to configure on the API side. You might have missed  to enable CORS in your WebSecurityConfig.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and()...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did but I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

**If you plan to deploy backend and frontend to the same server**,  I would do it in a different manner; by [proxying your frontend to your backend](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server):

Create a proxy.config.json file with the endpoints you want to hit:

```json
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/api/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

Then update your angular.json to include the proxy config:

```json
...
"architect": {
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      },
...
```

In this manner calls to `http://localhost:4200/api/somesecretAPI` will be forwarded to  `http://localhost:8080/api/somesecretAPI` and when you deploy it to your prod environment you don't have to configure anything (or you can do some mod_rewrite stuff in .htaccess on apache).

Answer (score 0):

To apply Spring security we will add the below dependency Maven:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```